# Running a number of consecutive replacements on the same string

Tags: rust

I found this example for substring replacement:

```
use std::str;
let string = "orange";
let new_string = str::replace(string, "or", "str");
```

If I want to run a number of consecutive replacements on the same string, for sanitization purposes, how can I do that without allocating a new variable for each replacement?

If you were to write idiomatic Rust, how would you write multiple chained substring replacements?

Comment: Do you need more than a byte-wise replacement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how would you write multiple chained substring replacements?

I would do it just as asked:

```
fn main() {
    let a = "hello";
    let b = a.replace("e", "a").replace("ll", "r").replace("o", "d");
    println!("{}", b);
}
```

It you are asking how to do multiple *concurrent* replacements, passing through the string just once, then it does indeed get *much* harder.

This does require allocating new memory for each `replace` call, even if no replacement was needed. An alternate implementation of `replace` might return a [`Cow<str>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) which only includes the owned variant when the replacement would occur. A hacky implementation of that could look like:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

trait MaybeReplaceExt<'a> {
    fn maybe_replace(self, needle: &str, replacement: &str) -> Cow<'a, str>;
}

impl<'a> MaybeReplaceExt<'a> for &'a str {
    fn maybe_replace(self, needle: &str, replacement: &str) -> Cow<'a, str> {
        // Assumes that searching twice is better than unconditionally allocating
        if self.contains(needle) {
            self.replace(needle, replacement).into()
        } else {
            self.into()
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> MaybeReplaceExt<'a> for Cow<'a, str> {
    fn maybe_replace(self, needle: &str, replacement: &str) -> Cow<'a, str> {
        // Assumes that searching twice is better than unconditionally allocating
        if self.contains(needle) {
            self.replace(needle, replacement).into()
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = "hello";
    let b = a.maybe_replace("e", "a")
        .maybe_replace("ll", "r")
        .maybe_replace("o", "d");
    println!("{}", b);

    let a = "hello";
    let b = a.maybe_replace("nope", "not here")
        .maybe_replace("still no", "i swear")
        .maybe_replace("but no", "allocation");
    println!("{}", b);
    assert_eq!(b.as_ptr(), a.as_ptr());
}
```

Comment: How do you go from `str::replace(string, "or", "str");` to being able to chain method calls on string objects? That is, why does that work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... You can just call it: `"hello".replace("h", "y")`.

Comment: Is this simmilar to how D can turn `method(str, arg)` into `str.method(arg)`? In case you're not familiar with D, the compiler turns the latter into the former at compile time transparently.

Comment: I think D refers to that as Universal Function Call Syntax (UFCS), and Rust *has* something called UFCS, but as far as I know, they are different. In this case, there are **two** definitions of `replace`: a [free function](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.replace.html) and a [trait method](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.StrAllocating.html#tymethod.replace).

Answer (score 14):

The [regex engine](https://crates.io/crates/regex) can be used to do a single pass with multiple replacements of the string, though I would be surprised if this is actually more performant:

```
extern crate regex;

use regex::{Captures, Regex};

fn main() {
    let re = Regex::new("(or|e)").unwrap();
    let string = "orange";
    let result = re.replace_all(string, |cap: &Captures| {
        match &cap[0] {
            "or" => "str",
            "e" => "er",
            _ => panic!("We should never get here"),
        }.to_string()
    });
    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Comment: As of version 1.0.5 of the regex crate, the `.to_string()` in `match &cap[0] { ... }.to_string()` is not needed, since the `Regex::replace_all` closure can return any `T: AsRef<str>`, not just `String`. So it can return string literals (`&'static str`) directly.

Comment: Suppose I have a capture group with special characters and placeholders, how would I go about that in the match directive? I don't know the match in the beginning, so spelling out the whole possible match won't work.

Answer (score 10):

I would not use regex or `.replace().replace().replace()` or `.maybe_replace().maybe_replace().maybe_replace()` for this. They all have big flaws.

- Regex is probably the most reasonable option but regexes are just a terrible terrible idea if you can at all avoid them. If your patterns come from user input then you're going to have to deal with escaping them which is a security nightmare.
- `.replace().replace().replace()` is terrible for obvious reasons.
- `.maybe_replace().maybe_replace().maybe_replace()` is only very slightly better than that, because it only improves efficiency when a pattern doesn't match. It doesn't avoid the repeated allocations if they all match, and in that case it is actually worse because it searches the strings twice.

There's a much better solution: Use [the Aho-Corasick crate](https://docs.rs/aho-corasick/latest/aho_corasick/struct.AhoCorasick.html). There's even an example in the readme:

```rust
use aho_corasick::AhoCorasick;

let patterns = &["fox", "brown", "quick"];
let haystack = "The quick brown fox.";
let replace_with = &["sloth", "grey", "slow"];

let ac = AhoCorasick::new(patterns);
let result = ac.replace_all(haystack, replace_with);
assert_eq!(result, "The slow grey sloth.");
```

> for sanitization purposes

I should also say that blacklisting "bad" strings is completely the wrong way to do sanitisation.

Comment: Surprisingly, *Go* has similar package in *stdlib*: https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Replacer

Comment: go's replace doesn't mention Aho-Carasick, do they use a less efficient algorithm?

Comment: You have to unwrap before replace_all

Answer (score 3):

There is no way in the standard library to do this; it’s a tricky thing to get right with a large number of variations on how you would go about doing it, depending on a number of factors. You would need to write such a function yourself.

Comment: I know that in Ruby, I can chain gsub together, and will do the right thing. I figure Rust could do the same, if the replace function were a method of the string object. But it isn't. If you were to write idiomatic Rust, whatever that means, would you just make a new variable for each step?

Comment: It would depend on what I was doing and the nature of the replacements. Is it a character-wise translation? Are all the from/to pairs equivalently sized or not? How many are there? I would always be inclined to write it as multiple chained replacements initially until I *knew* performance was going to be an issue.

Answer (score -4):

Stumbled upon this in codewars. Credit goes to user [gom68](https://www.codewars.com/users/gom68)

```
fn replace_multiple(rstring: &str) -> String {
  rstring.chars().map(|c|
      match c {
          'A' => 'Z',
          'B' => 'Y',
          'C' => 'X',
          'D' => 'W',
          s => s
      }
  ).collect::<String>()
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with mult-character strings, which appear in the OP.