# How to repeatedly perform string replacement in a loop?

Tags: string, replace, rust, ownership

I am writing a method to loop through a `(from, to)` of a map and perform multiple rounds of `tmp = tmp.replace(from, to)`. I am still trying to grasp the ownership concepts of Rust

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate lazy_static;

use std::collections::HashMap;

lazy_static! {
    static ref REPLACEMENTS: HashMap<&'static str, &'static str> = {
        let mut m = HashMap::new();
        m.insert("abc", "def");
        m.insert("com", "org");
        m
    };
}

fn replace_path_name(path: &str) -> &str {
    let mut tmp = path;

    for (from, to) in REPLACEMENTS.iter() {
        let a = *from;
        let b = *to;

        tmp = tmp.replace(a, b);
    }

    tmp
}

fn main() {}
```

This code gets me...

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:22:15
   |
22 |         tmp = tmp.replace(a, b);
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |               |
   |               expected &str, found struct `std::string::String`
   |               help: consider borrowing here: `&tmp.replace(a, b)`
   |
   = note: expected type `&str`
              found type `std::string::String`
```

The extra `a` and `b` are my attempts to get by why Rust made `from` and `to` become `&&str`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is your return value: `&str`. You are returning a reference to something, but what will *own* that value? You cannot return a reference to a local variable.

The second problem is the return type of [`str::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.replace), which is a `String`, not a `&str`. That's the cause of your error message: you are attempting to store a `String` in a variable where only a `&str` can be stored. You cannot do that.

The *easiest* fix is not the most efficient; unconditionally create a `String`:

```rust
fn replace_path_name(path: &str) -> String {
    let mut tmp = String::from(path);

    for (from, to) in REPLACEMENTS.iter() {
        tmp = tmp.replace(from, to);
    }

    tmp
}
```

You could also use a type like [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html) to save a little bit of allocation in some cases:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn replace_path_name(path: &str) -> String {
    let mut tmp = Cow::from(path);

    for (from, to) in &*REPLACEMENTS {
        tmp = tmp.replace(from, to).into();
    }

    tmp.into()
}
```

Which can even be returned so that no allocation occurs if no replacements exist:

```rust
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn replace_path_name(path: &str) -> Cow<str> {
    let mut tmp = Cow::from(path);

    for (from, to) in &*REPLACEMENTS {
        tmp = tmp.replace(from, to).into();
    }

    tmp
}
```

Or the functional equivalent using `Iterator::fold`:

```
use std::borrow::Cow;

fn replace_path_name(path: &str) -> Cow<str> {
    REPLACEMENTS
        .iter()
        .fold(Cow::from(path), |s, (from, to)| s.replace(from, to).into())
}
```

It's unfortunate that `str::replace` doesn't return a `Cow<str>`. If it did, no allocations would take place if no replacements were made.

See also:

- [Is there any way to return a reference to a variable created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32682876/155423)
- [Running a number of consecutive replacements on the same string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27476895/155423)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is my forth time trying to pick up Rust from Java. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Is this still the correct way? Will some sort of `.map()` on `tmp` perhaps be more efficient?

Comment: @Jay where do you propose that `map` method is implemented?

Comment: @Shepmaster Looking it up, looks like I got it confused with reduce. In Python it would be something like - `reduce(lambda orig_str, replace_pairs: orig_str.replace(*replace_pairs), [('word', new_word'), ('word2', 'new_word2')], 'word word2')`

Comment: @Jay sure, something [like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aec2e34dc06f7c29d5c136ad3802d88e). I wouldn't expect any major performance differences.