# How do I convert the string "[1, 2, 3]" into a Vec<u8>?

Tags: string, vector, rust, byte

I'm passing an encrypted message between client/server over TCP using [AES-GCM-SIV](https://github.com/RustCrypto/AEADs/tree/master/aes-gcm-siv). The received buffer is converted to `String` and divided into several `Vec<&str>` using

```rust
let v: Vec<&str> = buffer_string.split("?+").collect();
```

Example of v:

```
["POST / HTTP/1.1\\r\\n\\", "Uaxh5NUi098q", "178", "[162, 254, 28, 241, ... ]"]
```

`v[3]` should be the ciphertext as `Vec<u8>`. How can the vector be used as `Vec<u8>`?

```rust
iter().map(|c| *c as u8).collect()
```

would work with `chars`, not `&str`.

Here's a complete example [on the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=29fbf8d9b213af4918eed9befb17e4a5):

```
fn main() {
    let buffer_string = r##"POST /chat HTTP/1.1\r\n\?+rRMUG4Lg8Gi6?+178?+[136, 136, 144, 59, 173, 25, 204, 247, 151, 53, 2, 137, 100, 45, 198, 58, 65, 210, 134, 165, 163, 156, 136, 148, 46, 31, 16, 184, 179, 73, 220, 14, 113, 152, 85, 1, 233, 208, 53, 27, 124, 52, 41, 175, 86, 109, 134, 103, 93, 148, 208, 114, 123, 97, 18, 53, 149, 195, 51, 55, 213, 114, 184, 72, 109, 30, 217, 206, 212, 58, 253, 141, 9, 45, 173, 213, 96, 35, 77, 122, 113, 240, 22, 222, 194, 11, 123, 221, 176, 116, 161, 196, 84, 203, 203, 184, 140, 42, 169, 244, 211, 1, 189, 96, 16, 62, 173, 50, 65, 48, 176, 44, 176, 246, 246, 242, 18, 146, 105, 29, 13, 223, 185, 151, 114, 30, 27, 36, 48, 178, 16, 3, 250, 49, 229, 84, 121, 135, 197, 204, 42, 140, 220, 244, 73, 184, 250, 104, 125, 224, 219, 94, 111, 247, 92, 16, 168, 50, 249, 10, 65, 214, 217, 157, 7, 113, 217, 141, 174, 139, 183, 86, 17, 24, 221, 134, 222, 240]"##;

    let v: Vec<&str> = buffer_string.split("?+").collect();
    println!("Vector: v1 {:?}, v2 {:?}, v3: {:?}", v[1], v[2], v[3]);

    //only the v[3] is needed as vec<u8>
    //error with iter and &str
    //let ciphertext_vec: Vec<_> = v[3].iter().map(|c| c.parse::<u8>().unwrap()).collect();

    let ciphertext: Vec<u8> = [
        136, 136, 144, 59, 173, 25, 204, 247, 151, 53, 2, 137, 100, 45, 198, 58, 65, 210, 134, 165,
        163, 156, 136, 148, 46, 31, 16, 184, 179, 73, 220, 14, 113, 152, 85, 1, 233, 208, 53, 27,
        124, 52, 41, 175, 86, 109, 134, 103, 93, 148, 208, 114, 123, 97, 18, 53, 149, 195, 51, 55,
        213, 114, 184, 72, 109, 30, 217, 206, 212, 58, 253, 141, 9, 45, 173, 213, 96, 35, 77, 122,
        113, 240, 22, 222, 194, 11, 123, 221, 176, 116, 161, 196, 84, 203, 203, 184, 140, 42, 169,
        244, 211, 1, 189, 96, 16, 62, 173, 50, 65, 48, 176, 44, 176, 246, 246, 242, 18, 146, 105,
        29, 13, 223, 185, 151, 114, 30, 27, 36, 48, 178, 16, 3, 250, 49, 229, 84, 121, 135, 197,
        204, 42, 140, 220, 244, 73, 184, 250, 104, 125, 224, 219, 94, 111, 247, 92, 16, 168, 50,
        249, 10, 65, 214, 217, 157, 7, 113, 217, 141, 174, 139, 183, 86, 17, 24, 221, 134, 222,
        240,
    ]
    .to_vec();
    let ciphertext2: Vec<u8> = v[3].iter().map(|c| c.parse::<u8>().unwrap()).collect();
    assert_eq!(ciphertext, ciphertext2);

    // ciphertext: Vec<u8> =
}
```

Comment: `&str` has `as_bytes()`, which returns a `&[u8]`, which will probably work just fine. If you truly need a `Vec`, use `.as_bytes().to_vec()`.

Comment: I guess you are searching for this -> [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=23c6d14c76884326b42361636ed7a3d0)

Comment: Unfortunately `.as_bytes().to_vec()` won't work. `"[136, 136, 144,...]" will result in `[91, 49, 51, 54, 44, 32, 49, 51, 54...]` not `[136, 136, 144,...]`

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I convert a vector of strings to a vector of integers in a functional way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34090639/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Added an example with assert_eq! 
I am not able to make the solution in "How do I convert a vector of strings to a vector of integers in a functional way" working in my example, although they are similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that does it.

```
fn main() {
    let s = "[162, 254, 28, 241]";
    let v: Vec<u8> = s
        .trim_start_matches('[')
        .trim_end_matches(']')
        .split(',')
        .map(|c| c.trim().parse::<u8>().unwrap())
        .collect();

    for n in v {
        println!("{}", n);
    }
}
```

Try it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=70c1f58ed9ce0658ede98cdff3d724df).

Comment: input is a number like "162" or "254" not abc, op wants to convert "162":&str to 162u8

Comment: Note that in the example given by the OP, the array is bracketed by `[]`, so he will have to get rid of those

Comment: @Jmb I'm hesitating to add a simple `.replace()`... because it's too trivial...

Comment: Why do you use all those temporary bindings? That feels weird: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=72d5e7c94ffb8b8fd53199c7eec5d7f0

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios Because I come from a C++ background :D . I fixed my code ;-)

Comment: Thanks. That did it! [Here is an example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=29fbf8d9b213af4918eed9befb17e4a5) with the solution on the Playground:

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist Well, I wouldn't say that it needed to be "fixed", but that feels more idiomatic IMO.

Comment: @LazyEmpiricist Just be aware that using `unwrap` in production code is a bad idea.

Comment: Using `trim_{start,end}_matches` is more efficient than `replace`.

Comment: @Shepmaster I was curious about that. It was obvious that looping over the string twice isn't the best way to go. Can you please provide a playground example?

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=805dce9b741c905c1c928ca2d5a19de0. The *loops* are still there, but the *allocation* is removed. To remove the loops, see [Running a number of consecutive replacements on the same string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27476895/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks. Updated the code. The loop will be there anyway, that's a given. But it'll not loop over the whole string. Just from the beginning to the first instance, and to the last one from behind. That's the optimization I was looking for.

Comment: If you wanted to remove the multiple loops, you could split on multiple characters (`.split(&[',', '[', ']'][..])`), but only profiling would show which path is faster.

Comment: @Shepmaster I would use [`try_fold`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3509a042bc3d411e109e2e04aa74b040) instead of silently ignore the errors

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios I'd probably just use `collect` if I cared about the errors. Both versions (ignoring and keeping the errors) are presented in the duplicate question.